# Библиотека для подсчета заданных выражений c# (wpf)

Tags: c#, math

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста библиотеку, которая бы считала выражения заданного пользователем, будь то `1+ln55`, `sin89 + Pi/(cos(22))` ну и тд Конечно, все это можно написать самому, но когда есть либа, в которой уже все встроено, то это гораздо легче. Спасибо всем заранее

Comment: это выражения а не уравнения

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет `Math.NET Symbolics`

Comment: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics

Comment: Только вместо `1+ln55` нужно писать `1+ln(55)` это не ограничение библиотек а нормальная математическая запись.

Comment: Пример: `let expr = Infix.parseOrUndefined "1+ln(55)"
let result = Evaluate.evaluate Map.empty expr `

Comment: спасибо большое. Не подскажите, есть ли встроенное значение Пи ? или его вручную придется вводить ?

Comment: @Lolidze  Есть : `pi`

Comment: Если у вас возникнут какие-либо вопросы по работе с этой библиотекой, просто сделайте мне пинг [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)

Comment: Пинг делается следующим образом, ставится собачка и дальше ник или его сокращение, например `@Foggy` тогда придет сообщение, что к вам было обращение